# Please help explain the step used in this problem.

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

[image]

The figure above is from International Mathematics Olympiad Shortlist for 2006. The solution goes by induction. How did the authors obtain $a_1 = 1/2$ for the base case?

Please I need a clear explanation, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{a_{n-k}}{k+1} =0 \, \,, \, \, n \geq 1$$

Thus, when $n=1$, we have with us: $$\sum_{k=0}^{1} \frac{a_{1-k}}{k+1}=0$$ $$\implies \frac{a_1}{1} + \frac{a_0}{2}=0$$ $$\implies a_1=-\frac{\color{red} {a_0}}
 {2} \bigg \lvert_{\color{red} {a_0=-1}}$$ $$\boxed{a_1=\frac12} $$

Answer (score 0):

Because for $n = 1$, we have $$\sum_{k=0}^{1} \frac{a_{n-k}}{k+1} = a_1+\frac{a_0}{2} = 0$$ Since $a_0 = -1$, we have $a_1 = \frac{1}{2}$.